# Unequal sample sizes for npmv

Tags: r, nonparametric, manova

I have a similar question as this: [Nonparametric test for MANOVA in R violation of homogeneity and unequal group sizes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368439/nonparametric-test-for-manova-in-r-violation-of-homogeneity-and-unequal-group-si/392365#392365) which is unanswered.

I have a dataset for which I want to perform a MANOVA. However, my multivariate data (9 measurements on each 152 independent observations) failed all tests for normality and homogeneity of variance which led me to the R package npmv but I also have unequal sample sizes among groups (n=3, n=4, n=10, n=15, n=36, n=85). Specifically I am wondering if the permutation test of Wilks' lambda is still a viable way to test the global null hypothesis of no difference among groups given their varying sizes? The article for the citation of this package says it is robust for non-normal data and uses a rank based approach (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/npmv/index.html).